# Is it possible to use @ with the parameter in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a bash for script for nagios dns check. Im not sure if bash will read the parameter with @ sign. for example `dig -b 10.0.0.1 @194.xx.xxx.xxx www.example.com +short`.

I want to replace the `192.xx.xx.xx` with `@$1` instead of hard coding the host. Is this possible?

Comment: Ever tried it? What was the error?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You just have to enclose `@$1` in `""`:

```
"@$1"
```

So in your bash script you will have something like:

```
dig -b 10.0.0.1 "@$1" ...
```